# Does replacing the "_id" field in mongodb with a custom unique key decrease performance?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a situation in which I have a User schema that contains a unique field called "username." At the same time, mongo automatically creates its own unique key, "_id."

I've noticed that for a lot of my schemas I need both an array of "usernames" as well as "ids". This is quite redundant sometimes so my question is:

Is a lookup via "_id" faster than a lookup for a field "username" (let's say a 10 character string)? If they are the same, is it viable to use my unique identifier username for the value of _id?

Comment: If you ever allow changing of username values, consider the impact to your data models if you've stored it as a key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data naturally has a required, unique field, then it's perfectly fine to use that value as your `_id`.

As long as the field's data is comparable in size to an ObjectId (which is 12 bytes), then performance should be the same.  A 10 character string is 20 bytes, so the index for username will take a bit more memory, but probably not enough to make a difference performance-wise.

Since you're using Mongoose, you could also create a virtual field (named `username`) that exposes the `_id` field using that more descriptive name, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is fine, UNLESS you will be changing the structure of your usernames in the future. Thus I think it's better to just stick with ObjectId() for the ID and then stick an extra field `username` if you need it.